# Using NPM in server side - Salesforce

Tags: apex, integration, json, webservices, package

We have an external service which we send data (a JSON) to them, with some details - that also includes personal data such as mobile phone number and country ISO code.

I would like to use the Google service (libphonenumber - https://github.com/google/libphonenumber)
to check the validity of a mobile phone number in a specific country.

All of this needs to happen on the server-side.

how can I install a package on my org and use it in Apex code? (This is even possible?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [Salesforce Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide) to do this, but the program is still in Beta, meaning you have to sign up for it, and it likely won't be available in Production orgs for a while. Until then, you can always spin something up on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) or another service, and make a callout to get the results you want. Of course, you can't callout during a trigger, so you'll need some asynchronous code or flow if you need it to trigger on a DML operation, but the main point is that options are available to you if you absolutely need this server-side.

Comment: Many thanks. Heroku is great idea !